# Filter by First Day of the month

Tags: sql, mdx

I'm trying to filter a measure to only calculate for the first day of the month.

My basic query below is gathering all the days in the month. I can't seem to gather measures only for the first day of each month.

Desired results:

```
2016-01-01          $100
2016-02-01          $200
2016-03-01          $500

Select 
{ [Measures].[Sales] }
ON 0,

{ [Date_Fixed].[Date].&[2016-01-01]:NULL }
ON 1,

FROM DB
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql server you can do something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0) AS FirstOfTheMonth
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for SQL Analysis, MDX query